# How do I append to a file downloaded from libcurl?

Tags: c, macos, libcurl

I know that this *seems* simple, but this is a large bug in my program I've been agonizing over. Simply put, I want to have libcurl download a file from an FTP server, append text to that file, and then upload the file back to the server. My problem is that instead of appending text to the file, my program is overwriting the file's contents, even though when I'm writing to the downloaded file I'm using the a+ file operation mode in fopen(). If anyone has done anything like this before, some advice would be appreciated. Here's the relevant C code:

```
void write_to_database(const char* filename, const char* string_to_write) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "a+");
    if (file) {
        printf("Current position in file: %li\n", ftell(file));
        fputs(string_to_write, file);
        fputs("\n", file);
        fclose(file);
    }
}
…
void perform_database_modification(const char* file_to_write, const char* short_database, const char* addr, const char* msg) {
    strcpy(DATABASE_FILE, file_to_write);
    //strcpy(DESTINATION_MUSIC_FILE, music_file);
    strcpy(REMOTE_URL_HEAD, "");
    strcpy(REMOTE_DATABASE_FILE, short_database);
    strcpy(REMOTE_URL, addr);
    strcpy(message, msg);

    remove(DATABASE_FILE);

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    struct FtpFile ftpfile={
        DATABASE_FILE, /* name to store the file as if succesful */
        NULL
    };

    /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    /* get a curl handle */
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        /* specify target */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, REMOTE_URL);
        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        printf("Remote URL: %s\n", REMOTE_URL);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curl_database_write);
        /* Set a pointer to our struct to pass to the callback */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &ftpfile);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, (char *)loginUser);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, (char *)loginPassword);

        fprintf(stderr, "Using: %s %s\n", loginUser, loginPassword);

        /* Now run off and do what you've been told! */
        fflush(stdout); // Flush the buffers so we see the message immediately.
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /* Check for errors */
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "DWNLD DATAB: curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
            if (strcmp("Remote file not found", curl_easy_strerror(res)) != 0) // We are using this to see if remote file exists,
            {                                                                  // so ignore if the error is about that.
                [SBErrorNotice performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showError:) withObject:@(curl_easy_strerror(res)) waitUntilDone:NO]; // Show in main thread b/c NSAlert will complain otherwise.
                errorOccurred = true;
            }
        }

        if(ftpfile.stream)
            fclose(ftpfile.stream); /* close the local file */
    }

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    /* Now see if the file we downloaded exists. */
    if (file_exists(DATABASE_FILE))
    {
        printf("Database file exists.\n");
        write_to_database(DATABASE_FILE, message);
    } else {
        printf("Music index does not exist. Uploading a blank file...\n");
        create_blank_file(DATABASE_FILE);
        write_to_database(DATABASE_FILE, message);
    }
    //write_to_database(DATABASE_FILE, message);

    curl_global_cleanup();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the output from your "Current position in file"? Have you tried seeking to the end of the file?

Comment: Current position in file is somewhere in the 500s, don't have it running so I don't know. I didn't try to seek to the end of the file because I believe fputs() writes from the current location.

Comment: Yes, fputs should write from the current location. I was just trying to see what you had tried. It may be worth trying that. Is 500 about the size you expect? Also, I'm sure the curl bit is irellevant, so you should be able to just write to any file you have locally on your machine, which may make the problem easier.

Comment: The idea is that I need I need to download a file, write text to it, and then upload it back. All of that works EXCEPT for writing text to the file: the code truncated the file and writes from the beginning rather than appending the contents. And, yes, 500 is a reasonable size.

Comment: The idea is that I need I need to download a file, write text to it, and then upload it back. All of that works EXCEPT for writing text to the file: the code truncated the file and writes from the beginning rather than appending the contents.

Comment: Yes, and my point is that you can test the "update the file" bit separately from the rest of the code, which makes the code simpler, and you may be able to come up with a complete program that you can post here, showing the problem (unless you solve the problem in the process) - I know several other members here cut'n'paste the code from here onto their machine and try it. But that only works if you have a complete piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real answer, but it's too long to fit in a comment as such.

I just wrote this little program to test the principle:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void append_string_to_file(const char *filename, const char *string)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "a+");
    if (f)
    {
        printf("Appending string to file %s\n", filename);
        fputs(string, f);
        fclose(f);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
         append_string_to_file(argv[i], "This string is added to end of file...\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And in my testing, it performs exactly as expected. Since using CURL is unlikely to affect the ability of "stdio.h" functions to operate correctly, I think you need to take your code apart and see which part does what wrong. For example, is it possible that you have some special character in the file that causes problems (CTRL-Z in a Windows text file, for example)?

Also, you could try the above code on a sample file in your system, and see whether that works. If it works, then one can expect that your code you posted also works...

Comment: Okay, following your principles, I'll write a small program demonstrating what I'm attempting to do.

Comment: Hello again, I've written a sample program and a new question, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511790/changes-being-made-to-a-file-downloaded-with-libcurl-dont-take-effect