# Changes being made to a file downloaded with libcurl don't take effect

Tags: c, macos, libcurl

Let me explain in more detail. I'm trying to write a program that downloads a file from a remote FTP server, appends one line to the end of it, and then re-uploads it. The file operations work, and the text is appended to the file and re-uploaded, but when I download the file again, no text was appended. I've written a small test program to demonstrate this; here's the code at Pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/r07TkxEK

The program prints the following output on both the initial run and subsequent runs::

```
Remote URL: ftp://orangesquirrels.com
Got data.
Local data file size: 678 bytes.
Current position in file: 678
Uploading database file back to server...
Local data file size: 690 bytes.
Remote URL is ftp://orangesquirrels.com !
*** We read 690 bytes from file.
```

If the program works, the output from the subsequent run **should be**:

```
Remote URL: ftp://orangesquirrels.com
Got data.
Local data file size: 690 bytes.
Current position in file: 690
Uploading database file back to server...
Local data file size: 702 bytes.
Remote URL is ftp://orangesquirrels.com !
*** We read 702 bytes from file.
```

Because the data is written to the file and re-uploaded (I know this because the uploaded file is a greater size than the downloaded file) I assume the upload worked; my suspicion is that the problem lies in the download process and/or the `curl_database_write` function. I've been doing everything humanely possible to find out why this is happening, to no avail. If anyone knows *anything* about why this isn't working, I'd love to know. I'm being paid to write this program, and I know I've got to find a solution soon...

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't some caching server?

Comment: Yes, if I change this program to write a different string and then download the uploaded file, the file contains the new string. This is within seconds of each other so I assume there's no caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not using "short_database" nor "file_to_write" in your download()-function. So you download /tmp/musiclist.txt from the ftp-server instead of musiclist.txt.

you should check your defines, and when you use a define and when you use a stringvariable and when you use parameters

```
#define DATABASE_FILE "/tmp/musiclist.txt"
#define REMOTE_DATABASE_FILE "musiclist.txt"

int main() {
  remove(DATABASE_FILE);
  download(DATABASE_FILE, "musiclist.txt", REMOTE_URL, "Testing 123");
  //                         ^^^ should't this be REMOTE_DATABASE_FILE?
  ...
}

void download(const char* file_to_write, const char* short_database, const char* addr, const char* msg) {
  remove(DATABASE_FILE);    // again?!?

  struct FtpFile ftpfile={
      DATABASE_FILE, /* name to store the file as if succesful */
//    ^^^ which one? file_to_write or short_database
      NULL
  };
```

Comment: The code I wrote downloads the files. Yeah, I have some unused parameters, but I pulled this thing together quickly from the project exhibiting the bug; this is meant to be a test case, not a complete program, so I don't see how your comment helps my problem.

Comment: file_to_write is DATABASE_FILE and short_database is REMOTE_DATABASE_FILE.

Comment: download DOES NOT load the file (/tmp/musiclist.txt) you put on the server (/musiclist.txt (path added))

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed the problem using an entirely different method suggested by the folks on the mailing list. But I'll mark your answer as accepted because it is correct and you did take the time to answer.